# Haskell List of List Type Error

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

In GHCi, i type

```
let xs = [1, 'a']
```

it complains the error immediately:

```
<interactive>:28:11:
No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘1’
In the expression: 1
In the expression: [1, 'a']
In an equation for ‘xs’: xs = [1, 'a']
```

However, when I type

```
let xs = [1, [1, 1]]
```

It just passed. And it complains when I try to print xs:

```
<interactive>:5:1:
No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from a use of ‘it’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I think Haskell is a static type language so any type error should be caught in compile time. I am wondering why the above 2 errors are caught at different time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`1` is a polymorphic value of type `Num a => a`. So in `[1, [2, 3]]`, we have `[2, 3] :: Num a => [a]`; since all list elements must have the same type, we conclude that we must have `1 :: Num a => [a]`. That's a bit weird -- it's odd to think of `1` as having a list type -- but can be perfectly valid if somebody creates a sufficiently weird instance of `Num`. Checking whether an instance exists is pushed off until you try to use the instance; this gives you a chance to define the instance after you've defined the value using the instance. So it doesn't complain until you try to actually do something with the list `[1, [2, 3]]`.

Just to illustrate what I mean, one may write:

```
instance Num a => Num [a] where
    fromInteger n = pure (fromInteger n)
    (+) = liftA2 (+)
    (-) = liftA2 (-)
    (*) = liftA2 (*)
    abs    = liftA abs
    signum = liftA signum
```

(Indeed, this instance works for any `Applicative`, and is occasionally even useful.) Then, in ghci:

```
> let xs = [1, [1, 1]]
> xs
[[1],[1,1]]
```

See ma, no errors!

Comment: Why doesn't the same reasoning apply to a potential `Num Char` instance though?

Comment: @ReidBarton Good question! I'm actually not sure about that. I would guess that during instance resolution, GHC refuses to delay finding evidence for monomorphic constraints; but that's just a guess.

Comment: You could define a `Num Char` instance based on the `Enum Char` instance. The same reasoning would apply, but the instance just isn't included here.

Comment: @DanielWagner, sounds plausible, and I guess the reason why it does not eagerly solve the constraint in the polymorphic case is not because you might define an instance `Num [a]` later (same is true for `Num Char`), but because (with FlexibleInstances) there might be some specific instances like `Num [Double]`, and then you could use `xs` at type `[[Double]]`. In other words, GHC doesn't know what constraint to try to solve yet.

Comment: This is kind of toooo deep for me, I am just a beginner in FP....takes time to digest your answer. Anyway, thanks a billion....